# Error while cleaning project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting the following error dialog box when I clean the project.

> 'Cleaning selected projects' has encountered a problem.
>
> Error occured during the build.

And this is not the case while running all the projects, it gives the error for one project only. And it hangs eclipse when I right click on package explorer to any folder of this project.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: see in Problems in Eclipse may be there is some description about this dialog.

Comment: Have you restarted you Eclipse?

Comment: I have check it,in problems, there is not any description about this dialog.

Comment: @Spk yes, so many times I restarted it, still it can not clean that project only, for rest of projects it wrks fine.

Comment: Have you checked @MikeIsrael answer. Because, sometimes its happening here also. Or have you add any external `jar` files

Comment: @Spk I hv got solution, please check my answer.. thanks for ur time to help me.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any project dependencies?  I had a similar issue when I had a library project and it was cleaning the project that depended on the library project before the library (or something like that)

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my problem.. I deleted project from my eclipse and then same project I did import and then right now everything is ok. Now it is not giving error while I clean the project and also now pc does not hangs on right click on folder.
That might be problem because of svn project.

Thanks to all for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

a lot of times, this happens because you called your XML files in illegal names (capital characters or using dashes) try looking over your `res` folder and make sure non of those are present.

the only acceptable format is using [a-z0-9'_']

Comment: thnks for answer, but I have used all xml file names as per format.. so it is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

check the console for it, there will be some notices in there like error in any xml file, it occurs mostly because of failed to generate the R.java file and can not create R.java file when something wrong with any xml file or library you chosen to integrate with project.

```
Error during the build
```

It means that something is going wrong when the apk is generated, you wont get any error before building. So better, you check if you have added any library which violates the android dependency such as using awt,applet or any other package that android or DDMS dont support.
If you using latest android SDK(r17), then there are many issues in this SDK, please refer the develorper's site for that cos there are many changes in order of project building sources.

Comment: thnks for trying to help, but in console it is not giving any error for any xml file. and my R.java file has been created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Check your resources u created if any missing or apply some resource but not created.
Check your Libraries if u imported manuly some custom library in  **Project->RightClick -> Properties-> JavaBuildPath -> Project Tab**  which is not exist on source.
Check R.java file in **gen** folder build project successfully or not.

Comment: R.java file has been created... and my project is running successfully, but it gives error when I clean the project and I hangs eclipse when I right click on that project.

Comment: create new android project and check eclipse hangs on right click on project. If not then copy your project in new project and then try to clean your project.

Answer (score 1):

Check your xml files and clear error if you find anything. Some times string values or background resources are not available check them. Some times we will modify layouts like LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and imageview to button like that at this point some properties are not available in modified layout or view check them and remove. Finally try this Project>>RightClick>>Android Tools>>Fix Project Properties. and refresh the project clean again.

If it is not worked for you you have to create another project freshly and copy paste all the classes and xml files, drawables and all.

Answer (score 1):

This thread's a bit stale, but if it helps someone....

I had something similar, getting a Null Pointer Error during validation.  Here's what I did:

- Close Eclipse
- Go to the **Workspace** .metadata folder
- Open up the latest .log file
- Determine what's failing.
- Go into the .plugins folder and remove the related folder
- Re-open Eclipse

So, I was getting this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.DependencyIndex.getSet(DependencyIndex.java:102)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.DependencyIndex.set(DependencyIndex.java:223)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.Validator$V2.validate(Validator.java:1178)
...
```

The solution was then to delete `.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.validation`

I presume the database/data file inside was corrupted or out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem today for a couple of hours - on only one project.

I committed and pushed the project to Github and, lo and behold, the problem disappeared; cleaning is now happening perfectly normally.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: So, when your project is not working you commit it to GitHub? Kinda defeats the purpose of GitHub, doesn't it?

Comment: Haha yes, but it seems the problem was related to the interface between Eclipse and GitHub, and pushing my changes somehow cleared the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have restarted the Eclipse. Then can clean all projects. Its working for me.